# How to fix "Failed to execute child process source (no such file or directory)"

Tags: bash, ubuntu-16.04

I am trying to run a script in order to source my catkin workspace prior to running a driver.

This is the bash I am trying to run:

```
#!/bin/bash

gnome-terminal -e sudo systemctl start firmwared.service
sphinx /opt/parrot-sphinx/usr/share/sphinx/drones/bebop2.drone &

gnome-terminal -e source ~/bebop_ws/devel/setup.bash
roslaunch bebop_driver bebop_node.launch ip:=10.202.0.1
```

I get *failed to execute child process source (no such file or directory)* when running my bash

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Seems like the problem was the quoting, it should look like this

```
gnome-terminal -e "bash -c 'source ~/bebop_ws/devel/setup.bash;roslaunch bebop_driver bebop_node.launch ip:=10.202.0.1'"
```

Answer (score 1):

IF you want to use GUI on windows and failed then just use next command:

```
sudo apt-get install dbus-x11
```

Answer (score 0):

`source` is built into the shell, so you would have to do something like

```
gnome-terminal -e 'bash -c "source ~/bebop_ws/devel/setup.bash"'
```

Comment: Its not working, I am getting _[bebop_node.launch] is neither a launch file in package [bebop_driver] nor is [bebop_driver] a launch file name_ error because it seems like `gnome-terminal -e 'bash -c "source ~/bebop_ws/devel/setup.bash" ' ` is not correct

Comment: That sounds more like a problem with the setup.bash file you're trying to run than the command that I am trying to run. If you do `gnome-terminal -e 'bash -c "source test.bash"' where test.bash contains some simple commands, it should work.